# Can you go to a line in python?

Tags: python, line

I'm a new python user.
I don't know how to go to a certain line in the .py file
I'm trying to make like a 'restart button' so I don't need to re-run to open it again.

as example:

```
    print ("quizzes")
    a1 = input("do you want to try again?")

    if a1 = "YES" :
    {the code to get back to Line 1}
```

i am trying to get back to line 1 so they could answer the quiz again
if possible

Comment: provide a minimal coding example.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place to get this kind of help. You want a book or tutorial for the language.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
while(True):    
    print ("quizzes")
    a1 = input("do you want to try again?")

    if a1 == "NO" :
         break
```